# PHP - replace NAME to CLASS and strip onclick attribute

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
   $str =  'title="favorite" name="fav_1" onclick="return ..."'
```

I want to replace `name` to `class` and stripe `onclick` attribute.

**What I have tried ?:**

---

```
    $str = 'title="favorite" name="fav_12" onclick="return.."';

    $replace = str_replace('name', 'class', $str);
```

**Humm.. its okey. what is your problem ?**

---

If I use `str_replace` then I need to repeat this step two time, first for replacing `name` to `class` and second stripe `onclick` to blank space.

Repeating code is not a problem, but `str_replace` will not work If I dont know what is inside `onclick="..."`.

So please suggest how do I replacing name to class and stripping onclick just in single line of code.

Comment: [THE PONY HE COMES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: The `<center>` cannot hold!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use:

```
preg_replace('/onclick=".*"/', '', $str);
```

But you should look into a DOM parser, as the above would probably break at some point.

Comment: @user007 any reason you're ignoring [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Comment: No I am not ignoring this answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

```
$str = preg_replace('/onclick="([^"]+)"/', ' ', $str);
```

But if there are some quotes inside the onclick quotes, it'll fail (even if they're escaped with \).